# Metamorph script tags being added to value attribute in Ember/Sproutcore 2.0

Tags: ember.js

I have the following controller which contains a view:

```
Lead.Controllers.UrlSearch = Ember.Object.extend
  init: ->
    @_super()

    @url_search = Lead.UrlSearch.create()

    @url_search.set('search_url', 'http://www.bdec-online.com/bd-cmpy/bd-cz.cfm')

    @view = Ember.View.create
      controller: @
      urlSearchBinding: 'controller.url_search'
      templateName: 'app/templates/url_search/show'

    @view.appendTo('#fieldset')
```

The template at app/templates/url_search/show is as follows

```
<label for="url_search_url">Url</label>
<input id="url_search_url" name="url_search[url]" size="30" type="search" value="{{urlSearch.search_url}}">
<button class="button" id="goButton" type="button">GO</button>
```

The view is rendered fine apart from the value parameter which has the metamorph script tags in like this:

```
<input id="url_search_url" name="url_search[url]" size="30" type="search" value="&lt;script id='metamorph-0-start' type='text/x-placeholder'&gt;&lt;/script&gt;http://www.bdec-online.com/bd-cmpy/bd-cz.cfm&lt;script id='metamorph-0-end' type='text/x-placeholder'&gt;&lt;/script&gt;">
```

Is there anyway I can stop these script tags getting rendered or is there a config setting somewhere to stop this?

Comment: Additionally to the answers below, you can take a look at the excellent blog post http://www.emberist.com/2012/04/06/bind-and-bindattr.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is precisely why the {{bindAttr}} helper is available.  This should do the job for you:

```
<input id="url_search_url" name="url_search[url]" size="30"
 type="search" {{bindAttr value="urlSearch.search_url"}}>
```

Comment: Note that `bindAttr` is soft-deprecated in favor of `bind-attr` http://emberjs.com/blog/2013/08/29/ember-1-0-rc8.html

Comment: bindAttr is now depreciated. you should use bind-attr.
If you don't care to track the data changes for a property, use unbound.

Answer (score 14):

If you want to avoid your property output getting wrapped in these markers, use the unbound helper:

```
My new car is {{unbound color}}.
```

Your output will be free of markers, but be careful, because the output won't be automatically updated!

```
My new car is blue.
```

(see http://emberjs.com/#toc_handlebars-basics)